# Finding the number of continuous days per group with breaks in between, resetting cumulative sum on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
data = [['X','A','2022-05-01',True,True],
   ['X','A','2022-05-02',True,True],
   ['X','A','2022-05-03',True,False],
   ['X','A','2022-05-04',False,True],
   ['X','A','2022-05-05',False,True],
   ['X','A','2022-05-06',True,True],
   ['X','A','2022-05-07',True,False],
   ['X','B','2022-05-10',True,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-11',True,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-13',True,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-14',True,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-27',True,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-28',False,True],
   ['X','B','2022-05-29',True,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-01',True,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-02',True,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-03',True,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-04',False,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-05',False,True],
   ['Y','C','2022-05-06',False,True]]

columns = ['op_id','si_id','date','activity_level_1','activity_level_2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).astype({'date':'datetime64[ns]'})
> df

   op_id si_id        date  activity_level_1  activity_level_2
0      X     A  2022-05-01              True              True
1      X     A  2022-05-02              True              True
2      X     A  2022-05-03              True             False
3      X     A  2022-05-04             False              True
4      X     A  2022-05-05             False              True
5      X     A  2022-05-06              True              True
6      X     A  2022-05-07              True             False
7      X     B  2022-05-10              True              True
8      X     B  2022-05-11              True              True
9      X     B  2022-05-13              True              True
10     X     B  2022-05-14              True              True
11     X     B  2022-05-27              True              True
12     X     B  2022-05-28             False              True
13     X     B  2022-05-29              True              True
14     Y     C  2022-05-01              True              True
15     Y     C  2022-05-02              True              True
16     Y     C  2022-05-03              True              True
17     Y     C  2022-05-04             False              True
18     Y     C  2022-05-05             False              True
19     Y     C  2022-05-06             False              True
```

Where my data is sorted according to my required groupings already: `['op_id', 'si_id', 'date']`.

What I would like to to is the following: *per group* of `['op_id', 'si_id']`, find continuous (consecutive) date ranges where the condition of `activity_level_n` is also *true*, resetting the cumulative sum when it is false.

Example output:

```py
   op_id si_id        date  activity_level_1  activity_level_2  cum_activity_level_1  cum_activity_level_2
0      X     A  2022-05-01              True              True                     1                     1
1      X     A  2022-05-02              True              True                     2                     2
2      X     A  2022-05-03              True             False                     3                     1
3      X     A  2022-05-04             False              True                     1                     2
4      X     A  2022-05-05             False              True                     1                     3
5      X     A  2022-05-06              True              True                     1                     4
6      X     A  2022-05-07              True             False                     3                     1
7      X     B  2022-05-10              True              True                     1                     1
8      X     B  2022-05-11              True              True                     2                     2
9      X     B  2022-05-13              True              True                     1                     1
10     X     B  2022-05-14              True              True                     2                     2
11     X     B  2022-05-27              True              True                     1                     1
12     X     B  2022-05-28             False              True                     1                     2
13     X     B  2022-05-29              True              True                     1                     3
14     Y     C  2022-05-01              True              True                     1                     1
15     Y     C  2022-05-02              True              True                     2                     2
16     Y     C  2022-05-03              True              True                     3                     3
17     Y     C  2022-05-04             False              True                     1                     4
18     Y     C  2022-05-05             False              True                     1                     5
19     Y     C  2022-05-06             False              True                     1                     6
```

The above implies a `reset_index()` after whatever grouping operation (on `['op_id', 'si_id']` would get the job done.

The `activity_level_n` columns are not related to each other, I merely wanted to illustrate that I wish to do this for multiple boolean columns.

I tried the following so far:

```py
day = pd.Timedelta('1d')
breaks = (df['date'].diff() != day) | (~df['activity_level_1'])
df['breaks'] = breaks
df['cum_activity_level_1'] = df.activity_level_1.mask(breaks, False).groupby([df.activity_level_1, df.breaks]).cumsum()
```

but while this is close, is not quite what I want:

```py
   op_id si_id       date  activity_level_1  activity_level_2  breaks  cum_activity_level_1
0      X     A 2022-05-01              True              True    True                     1
1      X     A 2022-05-02              True              True   False                     2
2      X     A 2022-05-03              True             False   False                     3
3      X     A 2022-05-04             False              True    True                     1
4      X     A 2022-05-05             False              True    True                     1
5      X     A 2022-05-06              True              True   False                     4
6      X     A 2022-05-07              True             False   False                     5
7      X     B 2022-05-10              True              True    True                     1
8      X     B 2022-05-11              True              True   False                     6
9      X     B 2022-05-13              True              True    True                     1
10     X     B 2022-05-14              True              True   False                     7
11     X     B 2022-05-27              True              True    True                     1
12     X     B 2022-05-28             False              True    True                     1
13     X     B 2022-05-29              True              True   False                     8
14     Y     C 2022-05-01              True              True    True                     1
15     Y     C 2022-05-02              True              True   False                     9
16     Y     C 2022-05-03              True              True   False                    10
17     Y     C 2022-05-04             False              True    True                     1
18     Y     C 2022-05-05             False              True    True                     1
19     Y     C 2022-05-06             False              True    True                     1
```

as it's not resetting the cumulative sum. How can I achieve what I want?

Ideally, I would prefer to avoid `apply` as my dataframe has about ~7M rows, but if there's no other way I'm fine with it.

Comment: I just noted an inconsistency in your output, why is the B/2022-05-29/cum_activity_level_1 a `1`, but the A/2022-05-06/cum_activity_level_1 a `2`?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think `A/2022-05-06/cum_activity_level_1` should also be `1`, since I wish to count consecutive rows that match the condition. I must've made a mistake when writing those down, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) with a custom grouper for each column:

```
m1 = df.groupby(['op_id', 'si_id'])['date'].diff().ne('1D')

for col in ['activity_level_1', 'activity_level_2']:
    m2 = (m1 | ~df[col])
    # df['breaks'] = m2
    group = m2.cumsum()
    df[f'cum_{col}'] = (df.groupby(['op_id', 'si_id', group])
                        [col].cumcount().add(1)
                        )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   op_id si_id       date  activity_level_1  activity_level_2  cum_activity_level_1  cum_activity_level_2
0      X     A 2022-05-01              True              True                     1                     1
1      X     A 2022-05-02              True              True                     2                     2
2      X     A 2022-05-03              True             False                     3                     1
3      X     A 2022-05-04             False              True                     1                     2
4      X     A 2022-05-05             False              True                     1                     3
5      X     A 2022-05-06              True              True                     2                     4
6      X     A 2022-05-07              True             False                     3                     1
7      X     B 2022-05-10              True              True                     1                     1
8      X     B 2022-05-11              True              True                     2                     2
9      X     B 2022-05-13              True              True                     1                     1
10     X     B 2022-05-14              True              True                     2                     2
11     X     B 2022-05-27              True              True                     1                     1
12     X     B 2022-05-28             False              True                     1                     2
13     X     B 2022-05-29              True              True                     2                     3
14     Y     C 2022-05-01              True              True                     1                     1
15     Y     C 2022-05-02              True              True                     2                     2
16     Y     C 2022-05-03              True              True                     3                     3
17     Y     C 2022-05-04             False              True                     1                     4
18     Y     C 2022-05-05             False              True                     1                     5
19     Y     C 2022-05-06             False              True                     1                     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it!
in this case I think it's better to use `groupby` on `['op_id', 'si_id']` and apply a custom function that resets the cumulative sum when the condition is false

something like this :

```
def cumsum_reset(df, col):
    cumsum = df[col].cumsum()
    cumsum[~df[col]] = 0
    cumsum[df['date'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(days=1)] = 0
    return cumsum

cols = ['activity_level_1', 'activity_level_2']
for col in cols:
    df[f'cum_{col}'] = df.groupby(['op_id', 'si_id']).apply(lambda x: cumsum_reset(x, col)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

is it ok ?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite do it. For example, `B/2022-05-27/cum_activity_level_2` should be reset to `1`, because there's a jump in dates. Similarly for `B/2022-05-10/cum_activity_level_2` which should also reset to `1`.

Comment: @filpa I updated my answer check it out plz

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
        col2=dd.date.diff().fillna("1 days").ne("1 days").cumsum()
        return dd.assign(col2=col2)

def function2(dd:pd.DataFrame):
        col3=dd.date.diff().fillna("1 days").eq("1 days").cumsum()
        return dd.assign(col11=col3.where(dd.activity_level_1,1))\
                .assign(col12=col3.where(dd.activity_level_2,1))
df.assign(col1=df.activity_level_1.diff().cumsum().fillna(0))\
        .groupby(['op_id','si_id','col1'],as_index=False).apply(function1)\
        .groupby(['op_id','si_id','col1','col2'],as_index=False).apply(function2).drop(columns=['col1','col2']).pipe(print)
```

out：

```
 op_id si_id       date  activity_level_1  activity_level_2  col11  col12
0      X     A 2022-05-01              True              True      1      1
1      X     A 2022-05-02              True              True      2      2
2      X     A 2022-05-03              True             False      3      1
3      X     A 2022-05-04             False              True      1      1
4      X     A 2022-05-05             False              True      1      2
5      X     A 2022-05-06              True              True      1      1
6      X     A 2022-05-07              True             False      2      1
7      X     B 2022-05-10              True              True      1      1
8      X     B 2022-05-11              True              True      2      2
9      X     B 2022-05-13              True              True      1      1
10     X     B 2022-05-14              True              True      2      2
11     X     B 2022-05-27              True              True      1      1
12     X     B 2022-05-28             False              True      1      1
13     X     B 2022-05-29              True              True      1      1
14     Y     C 2022-05-01              True              True      1      1
15     Y     C 2022-05-02              True              True      2      2
16     Y     C 2022-05-03              True              True      3      3
17     Y     C 2022-05-04             False              True      1      1
18     Y     C 2022-05-05             False              True      1      2
19     Y     C 2022-05-06             False              True      1      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#find the days that are consecutive and true
m = df[['activity_level_1','activity_level_2']] & df.groupby(c)['date'].diff().dt.days.eq(1).to_numpy()[:,None]

#get the count, resetting on False
m.groupby([df['op_id'],df['si_id']]).transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().sub(x.cumsum().where(~x).ffill().fillna(0)).add(1))
```

Output:

```
    activity_level_1  activity_level_2
0                1.0               1.0
1                2.0               2.0
2                3.0               1.0
3                1.0               2.0
4                1.0               3.0
5                2.0               4.0
6                3.0               1.0
7                1.0               1.0
8                2.0               2.0
9                1.0               1.0
10               2.0               2.0
11               1.0               1.0
12               1.0               2.0
13               2.0               3.0
14               1.0               1.0
15               2.0               2.0
16               3.0               3.0
17               1.0               4.0
18               1.0               5.0
19               1.0               6.0
```